# What would be Perl's unpack representation in Java

Tags: java, perl, unpack

I have a Perl script where it takes a value and unpacks it into a few binary data attributes. Example as below

```
my ( $atr1, $atr2, $atr3, $atr4 ) = unpack('a3a16a32a*', $original_value);
```

I would like to know do I achieve the same with Java perhaps using `ByteBuffer` or some other means.

In this gist https://gist.github.com/enrobsop/8403717 it is done for integers but I'm still not clear on how to handle binary data.

Comment: What does `unpack` do in perl? Could [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) be what you're looking for?

Comment: it takes a string and expands it out into a list of values - https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack problem with my case is that the binary data

Comment: Don't ask to translate, ask to understand what something does in Perl, or ask how to do something in Java

Comment: @Switch yes I read that before commenting. But to me it's still not clear what "expands it out into a list of values" means. More precisely, it expands them based on what? Can you please give an example input and an expected output?

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca, Re "*it expands them based on what?*", They provided format (`a3a16a32a*`). See my answer for an explanation of what that means.

Comment: See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70141921/2173773) question

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, `C` is very different than `a`, though. `a` is a substring or slicing operation, while `C` is a deserialization operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That `unpack` returns four strings. Specifically, it returns the first 3 characters of the string value of `$original_value` as one string, the next 16 as another, the next 32 as another, and the rest as the fourth and final. Put differently, it returns four slices of the string: One from characters 0..2, one from characters 3..18, one from characters 19..50, and one from characters 51 on.

Note that Perl strings are quite different than Java's. Perl strings are strings of 72 bit characters<sup>[1]</sup> frequently used to store both text in the form of Unicode Code Points<sup>[2]</sup>, and bytes. Java strings, on the other hand, are strings of 16 bit characters used almost exclusively used to store text in the form of UTF-16 byte-pairs.

There is insufficient context to know whether the the string in `$original_value` is text or bytes (or something else). If it's bytes, the Java equivalent would use arrays of `byte` values or `ByteBuffer` objects rather than strings, and you'd use four calls to [java.util.Arrays's `copyOfRange`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int)) or [java.nio.ByteBuffer's `get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#get(byte%5B%5D)) to perform the operation. If it's text, there's no direct equivalent in core Java (according to my limited and ancient knowledge of Java).

---

1. Well, the internal encoding supports 72 bit characters, but only 32 or 64 bit characters are supported in practice.
2. Each character is a value in [0x000000,0x10FFFF], which is larger than a Java `char` can support. For example, `length("\N{U+100000}")` is `1`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, `$original_value` comes in text format, to be precise it's a base64 encoded string. But we know for sure that it includes binary values when we unpack (the second & the third attributes)

Comment: base64 encodes *bytes*, so `$original_value` does **not** contain text but a string of bytes, so use java.util.Arrays's `copyOfRange` or java.nio.ByteBuffer's `get`.